# Retrieve download URL for PFFile on Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I want to host a PDF generated in an ios app on Parse server and then retrieve a download URL from parse so that I can send the URL to print node to be printed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, in which app? JavaScript, iOS, Android?

Comment: It’s an iOS app

Comment: Ok, I am writing an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you need to first to create PFFile. 
Your PFFile should contain the PDF data and the content type of it (it's part of the PFFile constructor). It's important to provide the content type in order to view the PDF directly by clicking on the URL.

After you create the PFFile you **must** attach it to some PFObject in order to have access to it. So you first save the PFFile, after saving you attach it to PFObject in the following way:

```
    let pdfData = Data()
    let f = PFFile(data:pdfData , contentType: "application/pdf")
    let o = PFObject(className: "MyCustomClassName")
    o.setObject(f, forKey: "file")
    o.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
        // upon success the object will be available in parse-server.
    }
```

From the code above you can see that first you need to create pdfData (in my code is empty but in your code you will need to pass the content there). Then, you create a PFFile with data and contentType and then you assign it to PFObject and finally you save the object. In this code I assumed that you use [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX)  and you initialized it ahead.
In order to see the URL you can either go to your MongoDB search for "MyCustomClassName" collection and then you will see it there. I personally recommend you to use [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard) which will show you all your parse objects, files and more in a very nice and intuitive UI

Answer (score 1):

A `PFFile` on iOS has a `url` parameter that will be the url to reach your file.

Note that if you are doing local testing, with a locally hosted parse-server instance, the url may end up being "localhost:/" which will obviously not be accessible to the rest of the internet.

Here is a link to the iOS SDK's PFFile API reference: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFFile.html#/c:objc(cs)PFFile(py)url

Comment: How do I actually go about retrieving the url from the PFFile after saving the file?

Comment: I believe that `file.url` works on both Swift and Obj-C, though there's a chance obj c is actually `[file url]`.  I work more in Swift of late so I don't recall.  `file` must be a PFFile *after* the save occurred.  Note that while the file exists if you don't attach it to an object, you will have no way to retrieve that file without it being attached to an object, as another user mentioned.  And if you fetch an object with a file attached, you still need to load the file in order to access the data within, it doesn't get included with the fetch.

Comment: No problem!  A couple points for clarification - if you fetch an object with a file as one of the fields, that field *will* be a PFFile (or whatever the client SDK you're using calls it, Android does not use PFFIle), but the data won't be there until you load it.  The URL *will* be there, so if that's all you need at that point, you don't need to load the object.  The object still exists in your storage if you don't attach it to an object, but it's only accessible via that URL or directly from your storage, like Amazon S3, but that's for admin purposes, not an app user.  Always best to

Comment: attach the file to an object.  Also keep in mind, if you haven't set up external file storage, again like Amazon S3, your files get saved to the local server, which gets overwritten on deploys, so make sure you've set up that file storage.